# How to get three divs to display diagonally?

Tags: html, css

I will try to explain this as the best I can. I have two divs side-by-side. The right one has three paragraphs in it. The left one has an image, vertical text, and a second image. The first image should be in the top left corner, the vertical text should be centered horizontally and vertically, the second image should be in the bottom right corner.

```css
body {
  width: 8.5in;
}

.left-div {
  float: left;
  background: blue;
}

.right-div {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: red;
}

.left-img {
  float: left;
}

.big-text {
  background: orange;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 0 30px;
  float: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.right-img {
  float: left;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.bottom-div {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-div">
  <div class="left-img">
    <img src="smiley.gif" width="150">
  </div>
  <div class="big-text">
    <p>B<br>I<br>G</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right-img">
    <img src="smiley.gif" height="200">
  </div>
  <div class="right-div">
    <p>First paragraph.First paragraph.First paragraph.First paragraph.First paragraph.First paragraph.First paragraph.First paragraph.First paragraph.First paragraph.First paragraph.First paragraph.First paragraph.First paragraph.First paragraph.First paragraph.First
      paragraph.First paragraph.First paragraph.First paragraph.First paragraph.First paragraph.First paragraph.First paragraph.First paragraph.First paragraph.First paragraph.
      <p>Second paragraph. Second paragraph. Second paragraph. Second paragraph. Second paragraph. Second paragraph. Second paragraph. Second paragraph. Second paragraph. Second paragraph. Second paragraph. Second paragraph. Second paragraph. Second paragraph.
        Second paragraph.
        <p>Third paragraph. Third paragraph. Third paragraph. Third paragraph. Third paragraph. Third paragraph. Third paragraph. Third paragraph. Third paragraph. Third paragraph. Third paragraph. Third paragraph. Third paragraph. Third paragraph. Third
          paragraph. Third paragraph. Third paragraph. Third paragraph. Third paragraph.
  </div>
</div>
<div class="bottom-div">
  <p>Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph
    of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text.
</div>
```

Comment: Not 100% sure what you mean. Could you maybe mockup what you think it should look like in paint (or similiar) and post the image?

Comment: I formatted your code as snippet. Please provide proper URL's for your images, if their dimensions are relevant to the snippet and also try to specify in clear the desired outcome (a schematic picture with the layout could help).

Comment: In left div, do want to align image first, text bottom of first image , then image bottom of text?

Comment: check this codpen, might it help you. http://codepen.io/vaibhaviiit/pen/XMmExj?editors=1100

Comment: @Vaibhav Kumar the first image should be in the top left corner of that div, the text shoul be centered, and image 2 should be in the bottom right corner and aligned with the bottom of the second(right) div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap left and right divs into a container and use nested flexbox layout.

**[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aJvGNV)**

```css
body {
  width: 8.5in;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

img {
  vertical-align: top;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.left-div {
  background: blue;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.right-div {
  background: red;
}

.left-img {
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.big-text {
  background: orange;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 0 30px;
}

.right-img {
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.bottom-div {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-div">
    <div class="left-img">
      <img src="//dummyimage.com/150x150" width="150">
    </div>
    <div class="big-text">
      <P>B<br>I<br>G</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right-img">
      <img src="//dummyimage.com/100x200" height="200">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-div">
    <p>First paragraph.First paragraph.First paragraph.First paragraph.First paragraph.First paragraph.First paragraph.First paragraph.First paragraph.First paragraph.First paragraph.First paragraph.First paragraph.First paragraph.First paragraph.First paragraph.First
      paragraph.First paragraph.First paragraph.First paragraph.First paragraph.First paragraph.First paragraph.First paragraph.First paragraph.First paragraph.First paragraph.</p>
    <p>Second paragraph. Second paragraph. Second paragraph. Second paragraph. Second paragraph. Second paragraph. Second paragraph. Second paragraph. Second paragraph. Second paragraph. Second paragraph. Second paragraph. Second paragraph. Second paragraph.
      Second paragraph.</p>
    <p>Third paragraph. Third paragraph. Third paragraph. Third paragraph. Third paragraph. Third paragraph. Third paragraph. Third paragraph. Third paragraph. Third paragraph. Third paragraph. Third paragraph. Third paragraph. Third paragraph. Third paragraph.
      Third paragraph. Third paragraph. Third paragraph. Third paragraph. </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="bottom-div">
  <p>Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph
    of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want something like this?

```css
.container{
  margin: auto;
  outline: 2px solid green;
  width: 70%;
  height: 300px;
 }
span{
  float:right;
  font-size: 28px;
}
.div1, .div2, .div3{
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 100px;
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 100px;
  color: white;
}
.div1{
  background-color: blue;
}
.div2{
  margin-left: 33.2%;
  background-color: grey;
}
.div3{
  margin-left: 66.5%;;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"><span>I'm main DIV</span>
  <div class ="div1">hi, i'm first div </div>
  <div class ="div2">hi, i'm second div </div>
  <div class ="div3"> hi, i'm third div</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place divs in diagonal position using GRID.

```css
.parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: green;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 0px;
  grid-row-gap: 0px;
}

.child {
  background-color: greenyellow;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.div1 {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
}
.div2 {
  grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3;
}
.div3 {
  grid-area: 3 / 3 / 4 / 4;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Diagonal Divs in Grid</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <h3>Diagonal Divs in Grid</h3>
      <div class="parent">
        <div class="child div1">1</div>
        <div class="child div2">2</div>
        <div class="child div3">3</div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```